# nginx rewrite in proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, rewrite, proxypass

I need proxing to different backend but whith same url, so rewriting thould be
like this

```
URL: http://myservrer.com/server/monitoring1?(parameters) 
REWRITE TO: http://1.1.1.1/server/monitoring?(parameters)

URL: http://myservrer.com/server/monitoring2?(parameters) 
REWRITE TO: http://2.2.2.2/server/monitoring?(parameters)
```

My current config:

```
location /server/monitoring1 {             
proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:82/server/monitoring;                                                              
}
location /server/monitoring2 {             
proxy_pass http://2.2.2.2:82/server/monitoring;                                                              
}
```

How to change it with rewrite options?

Answer (score 0):

```
location /server/monitoring1 {             
    rewrite ^/server/monitoring1\?(.*) http://1.1.1.1:82/server/monitoring?$1 redirect;
}
location /server/monitoring2 {
    rewrite ^/server/monitoring2\?(.*) http://2.2.2.2:82/server/monitoring?$1 redirect;
}
```

Comment: This is a well-formatted example, but examples should not comprise the entire body of an answer. Adding a brief description of what you changed and why would be very helpful.

Comment: Well, the example above answers the question completely. He asked for a translation of his config using rewrites. That's what I did.