# How to use Nginx to both rewrite and proxy_pass whilst keeping the user-entered URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite, proxypass

I'm a beginner Nginx user trying to proxy the following:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/mypage/login
TO
http://some_ip_address/login
```

(not just /login - the site has other contexts too e.g. /static, /api, etc.)

Whilst I can functionally make this work, the user sees `http://some_ip_address` in their browser, which I'd like to avoid.

That config looks like this:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile      on;
    keepalive_timeout  3;
    server {
        server_name this_server_ip;
        location /mypage/ {
            proxy_pass http://some_ip_address;
            rewrite ^/mypage/(.*)$ http://some_ip_address/$1 last;
        }
        location / {
          root /var/local/directory/;
        }
    }
}
```

To try to fix it, I've tried combinations of:

- `proxy_pass http://some_ip_address/;` (i.e. with trailing slash)
- `proxy_set_header Host $host;`
- `rewrite ^/mypage/(.*)$ /$1 last;`

But I either get 404's or serve up the page that's hosted at `http://subdomain.example.com`, i.e. `rewrite` works but `proxy_pass` doesn't.

There are a few similar questions on serverfault but none seem to address my particular flavour of this problem, unfortunately. Examples are [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/586586/nginx-redirect-via-proxy-rewrite-and-preserve-url) and [that one](https://serverfault.com/questions/496979/nginx-rewrite-in-proxy-pass).

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why are you doing both `proxy_pass` and `rewrite` inside the location? You shouldn't need the `rewrite` here at all, since the `proxy_pass` kind of does the rewrite already. What does the logfile of `http://some_ip_address` tell you?

Comment: Without `rewrite`, Nginx tries to fetch a local resource, i.e. not from some_ip_address: `open() "/var/local/directory/login" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying `this_server_ip` as the hostname for this virtualhost. That means that this virtualhost isn't used for any requests that have a domain name, but your nginx default virtual server is used for requests for `http://subdomain.example.com/`.

You need to change your `server_name` to `subdomain.example.com`, or add `default_server` to the `listen` directive on this `server` block and remove it from the nginx default configuration.

EDIT: Try this vhost configuration:

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    location ~ /(mypage|static/api)/ {
        proxy_pass http://some_ip_address/$1/;
    }
    location / {
      root /var/local/directory/;
    }
}
```

That is, you don't need a `rewrite` statement at all, because you are proxying the request to another server.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though (and sorry it took me a little while to test it). To be clear, I used `server { server_name subdomain.example.com; listen 80 default_server; ... }`. I tried both with and without `proxy_pass` on my `location`, and also tried both `server_name`, `listen` and one or the other...

Comment: I changed the configuration, I had wrong idea here.